# "unsubscribe from this email" should not be so close to items - how to re-enable?

Tags: support, feature-request

I just got a "1 new items in Your Stack Exchange inbox" notification (about a comment replying to mine), and accidentally hit the "If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may *unsubscribe from this email*" link.

I didn't look very closely and was also in the mood of finding the *link to the post* *below* the post, as it is the case in many other notifications I get.
The two actions of visiting the post (the normal action) and of unsubscribing (a one-time, destructive action) are very close together in that email.
The unsubscribe link should be in the footer imo, together with the "feedback site" link.

Now how do I get back my notifications? Did I unsubscribe for that post only?

I see that I can select to get new responses by mail when posting a question, but what if I post a comment?
Or is that setting not even post-specific? After all, it says "Send me new responses to *my posts* via email", so I guess that affects all posts (and comments?). Then why is it above the "post your question" button - everything else above that is specific to a post. (I suggest you swap the "sen me new responses" and "answer your own question" checkboxes, making the former clearly distinct).

This is an area that needs usability work I guess.

Comment: Well, the unsubscribe-link *must* be obvious at first glance to avoid getting reclassified as spam, so the footer is out. Now making sure the other links aren't directly next to it, that might be doable...

Answer (score 1):

There's a [preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/524504) link on [your profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/524504/masterxilo), you can find subscription settings there.

[image]

[image]