# How can I unsubscribe from a topic?

Tags: discussion, subscriptions

I don't want to get any more notifications about *[What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep/39914235)*. Yes, last year I was very interested in it. But interests change.

```
1 new item in your Stack Exchange inbox

 Stack Overflow
  Inbox  The following item was added to your inbox since you last checked it on 2021-06-15:
  Stack Overflow.   comment  Sep 26 at 19:36
     What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?

     @Dan Dascalescu Does this sleep function clear the timeout at the end?
 See all of your inbox items: https://stackexchange.com/users/1133105?tab=inbox

  Edit email settings       Contact us       Privacy
```

"Edit email settings" won't turn this particular subject off.
*[Unsubscribe to old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296674/unsubscribe-to-old-questions)* didn't help.
*["unsubscribe from this email" should not be so close to items - how to re-enable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271660/unsubscribe-from-this-email-should-not-be-so-close-to-items-how-to-re-enable)* is about all topics, not this particular topic.
"Follow" is not pressed on the post.

Perhaps it is because I upvoted the topic. OK, I'll un-upvote it. Maybe that will unsubscribe me from updates... Alas, my "vote is now locked."

Comment: Note that you have [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep/39914235#comment118684811_39914235) on that answer once, and @reply doesn't work with whitespaces, so it will fallback to "@Dan". However, I still can't solve the mystery of [@reply's name matching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/241919) on why you still got the notification even though "Dan Dascalescu" (the OP of the answer) has commented after you.

Comment: @AndrewT. "_An exception is the case when the first `@name` either matched nobody, or matched the post's author (and thus isn't necessary); in this case, the next `@name` will be checked._" might be the reason.

Comment: Is this an email notification or a notification in your inbox here on the Stack Overflow site?

Comment: Both email and web notification.

I sure hope my name is OK.

Answer (score 10):

You're only getting notified because you've commented on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/1038015). If you no longer want to be notified, simply delete all your comments on that answer.

You'll have to expand the comment list to see them all.

Note that you can't be contacted in comments if all you've done is vote on a post.

Comment: That is terrible.
Let's say I'm some important person, and people cherish my comments.
The more I leave the more my mailbox gets ruined.
How could someone who left 458 comments still be interested in 458 topics?
So then everybody has to delete all their contributions just to restore their mailbox to peace? Doesn't sound like a good business model.

Comment: Indeed, for a user to figure out that he indeed [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep/39914235#comment118684811_39914235), at all, even if not way deep in the hidden comments, is a major research project. So  an hopeful future unsubscribe button should not be only buried there too. So unsubscribe buttons need to be: in the email, in the web notifications, and at the top of the page. Also the email and notifications need to say 'you are receiving this mail because you commented...(link), and someone followed up. If you no longer wish..."

Comment: "... to follow (just) this topic, then click..."

Comment: Well I've made 20 times the number of comments you have and I'm rarely bothered. Your 3 comments are all I've had today for instance. On those rare occasions where someone does pester me I have deleted my comments but really that's not often. You happened to comment on one highly visited post, your other 455 comments are unlikely to trouble you.